# Searching Gmail for conversations created by some email

Tags: search, gmail

I know I can search Gmail using `from:email` (and many other helpful similar searches) but this will return all the conversations where email is the sender of one of the messages in the conversation.

Is there a way to search for all the conversations that the sender of the first message in the conversation is some email?

Comment: thanks for the edit @Alex, although I would leave out the `@domain.com` because it is not mandatory to have a proper email there.

Comment: You are right, I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it could be helpful to use:

```
from:email -subject:"Re:"
```

Comment: should probably work as long as email is using an english email client (i.e. "Re:" could be in a different language.... ) I will wait a short while to see if there is a better solution and accept yours if no better one comes along.

Comment: may have to also have to account for forwards